# "mongo" command fails to connect

Tags: mongodb, connection, server, connect

I am trying to install MangoDB.  I have already installed the log and configure files.  When I run mongo command in mongodb/bin directory, I receive the error messages:
`mongo  MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4, connecting to: test
W NETWORK Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1)`

This is my mongod.cfg configure file; I don't know if it is correct.
`logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log
dbpath=C:\mongodb\data
rest=true`

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many more hurdles you can face during installation of mongodb. Installation of Mongodb is not as easy task I am also stuck with these issue for some time.the only option is to install mongodb step by step as described on Mongodb's official website.
Dont miss any step!.

here is the link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: I already did.  I don't think that I missed any step.  Sometimes instead of the above error, I receive an error that rest is not connected to http.  How the content of my configure file, i.e.,  "mongod.cfg" should look like?  Is there something that I maybe doing incorrectly?   Thanks.

Comment: @brian i face exctly same issue which you are facing right now.
the only extra thing i did i copy all files from C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin  to C:\MongoDB\bin .

Comment: I could install it once after following your instruction, but I got disconnected.  Now no matter how much I try it seems impossible to install it.  90% of the time I receive this message: "--rest is specified without --httpinterface"  "enabling http interface"   Do you know what does this mean?  I enabled httpinterface in mongod.cfg file, but it doesn't help.

Comment: When I go to Windows services, it says MongoDB status: running; start type: automatic.  So I guess this means that it is installed.